# Wordpress Fast Secure Contact Form - How to style the email?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have about 21 extra fields for a contact form and I need to style the email with HTML. Where should I begin to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Wordpress plug-in `Contact Form 7`